Next.js 13.5.4 Assets Not Loading on Deployment (App Routes, src/assets)
I'm encountering an issue with Next.js 13.5.4 where my assets located in the src/assets folder are not loading correctly when I deploy my application to UAT or production environments. This works perfectly during local development.
Details:
Next.js Version: 13.5.4
Deployment Platform: IIS Server
App Routes: I'm using app routes (experimental appDir: true in next.config.js).
Asset Folder Structure: src/assets (Describe the hierarchy if your assets are nested within src/assets)
What common reasons could cause this issue with Next.js 13.5.4 app routes and assets in the src folder?
Are there any specific configuration changes required for assets in the src folder when deploying to UAT/production?
How can I debug this issue further to pinpoint the exact cause?
